# How to create a survey template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Basically I have 3 tables: Survey, Questions, and Answers. I'm trying to decipher a way to create survey templates that can be re-used. Basically, user would go in, create a new survey name and description, and have the option to select 1 of 3 question templates, template 1, template 2, or create your own survey from scratch.

The issue is, I have no idea where to even start with this process. I'm new to Laravel and looking for some guidance. Please forgive me if this is something in the docs I've missed.

Here is my current create function in my Survey Controller, and my Model

```
public function create(Request $request, Survey $survey)
{
    $arr = $request->all();
    $arr['user_id'] = Auth::id();
    $surveyItem = $survey->create($arr);
    return Redirect::to("/survey/{$surveyItem->id}");
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Survey extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'user_id'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'surveys';

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there a question there? "How to create a survey template?" is pretty broad. You might need to narrow it down more and ask specific questions.

Comment: You could possibly add a template table and seed the database with...whatever sort of structure you are going for. Though I can't really give much more without knowing exactly all went into a template (ie: a set of questions or some other idea in mind).

Comment: Don't get hung up on the laravel. Write pseudo code first and focus on the ER diagram / design. Laravel is just PHP wearing an ascot.

Comment: Sorry for being so broad. The template would strictly be questions, their types,  and question options for mult choice and radio buttons. I'll look into seeding the db.

Comment: I guess the best way to phrase it, is there a way to pull an already existing set of questions from my question table, which belong to a survey, and re-use them when creating a new survey?

Comment: With seeding your database you can create the questions you want and hard code them to be referenced when a user creates a new survey using a given template.


When someone uses the template, depending on how you setup the relationship between survey and questions, you could have the survey reference that list of questions or you may have it create those template questions again.

It could also be accomplished by building an outside library that has those questions/templates loaded into an array and ready to be inserted as new rows into the DB when selecting a given template.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried